# Azure Fastlane auto increment build number

Tags: xcode, azure, fastlane, apple-tv

I've been trying to auto-increment the build number of my tvos app through the app release step in my azure pipeline.

I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops#apple-app-store) to create this step.

```
- task: AppStoreRelease@1
inputs:
  serviceEndpoint: 'Test Connection to App Store'
  appIdentifier: ${{ parameters.appIdentifier }}
  appType: 'tvOS'
  ipaPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.defaultArtifacts }}/build/*.ipa'
  releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
  shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
  shouldSkipSubmission: true
  fastlaneArguments: '--app_platform=appletvos --increment_build_number'
displayName: App Store Release
```

I want to use [this fastlane argument](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/) to increment my build number, but I'm not sure how I would do that in the yml format. I've tried to add it as an additional argument like:

```
fastlaneArguments: '--app_platform=appletvos --increment_build_number'
```

But, It throws an invalid argument error. Looking for anyone having experience with such a scenario who would like to share the wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this in the future, I managed to update the build number by adding the following step in the pipeline before creating an archive.

```
- script: fastlane run increment_build_number build_number:$(Build.BuildId) xcodeproj:Path_TO_PROJECT/app.xcodeproj
displayName: Update Build Number
```

Comment: where should I add this line??

Answer (score 1):

I took a very similar approach as @Subhan Ahmed

If you're not wanting to do it through Fastlane for whatever reason, here's a script that will work,

```
- script: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $(Build.BuildId)" "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Info.plist"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this approach. :)